# $\sqrt{1},\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\dotsc \sqrt{n}$. Calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu/\sigma$

Tags: limits, standard-deviation, means

The question is:
There is a collection of numbers:
$\sqrt{1},\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\dotsc \sqrt{n}$. 
$\mu$ is its arithmetic mean or average;
$\sigma$ is its standard deviation.
Calculate $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\mu}{\sigma} = \ ?$$

I think of the Squeeze Theorem, but I don't know how to do it, and maybe there is a more proper way to solve it. Can you help me, please?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: the limit appears to approach $2.85$ quickly and continually decrease very slowly. This is from mathematica `a[N_]:=Table[Sqrt[n],{n,1,N}];
Table[N[(Mean[#]/StandardDeviation[#])&[a[x]]],{x,2,200}]` If anybody has more computation time than me on wolfram lab or access to `NLimit`, feel free to test it out.

Answer (score 4):

Since $\sigma^2=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n(\sqrt k)^2-\mu^2=\frac{n+1}{2}-\mu^2$,
we have
$$\frac{\mu^2}{\sigma^2}=\frac{1}{\frac{n+1}{2\mu^2}-1}.$$
Therefore, we need to compute $\mu/\sqrt n$. We write it explicitly
$$\frac{\mu}{\sqrt n}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt\frac{k}{n}\to\int_0^1\sqrt x\mathrm dx=\frac{2}{3},$$
by the definition of Riemann integral.

Hence, we have $\mu^2/\sigma^2\to 1/((9/8)-1)=8$, and the limit is thus $2\sqrt2$.